# Number not exactly printed in the excel record file

Tags: php, php-5.3, zend-studio

I want to display unit numbers in front of Property name. I fetched my data in `$arrobjPropertyName` array object and in foreach loop I print it as

```
foreach( $arrobjPropertyName as $objProperty ) {
    $objWriteExcelWorksheet->write( $intRowCount, $intColumnCount++, $objProperty->getUnitNumber(), $objWorkbookContent );}
```

it will give the output 613 or 722 but i want it like 0613 or 0722 in excel record.

Please any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: `$objProperty->getUnitNumber()` will give you the number?

Comment: What Excel library are you using? It may allow you to set number format styling

Comment: I am using `CWriteexcelWorkbookBig.php  liabrary.

Comment: @Pradeep - do you have a URL for that library? So I can add it to the list of Excel reader and writer libraries that I maintain here on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach( $arrobjPropertyName as $objProperty ) {
    $objWriteExcelWorksheet->write( $intRowCount, $intColumnCount++, "'" . $objProperty->getUnitNumber(), $objWorkbookContent );}
```

you should tell excell it is a string. otherwise it will interpret as number and remove all leading 0s.

To be more elaborate:
if you type 0123 in excell manually, it will auto convert to 123. If you type '0123 in excell manually it will stay like 0123. So not only php has to know it is a string (so that php doens't remove the 0. but you must also tell excell excplicitly.

**Update:** sorry, forgot, excell only needs first '

Comment: Thanks......it works but single quote also print in output man which i dont want. just the number like 0123.

Comment: Very odd, my library picks it up OK and only prints 0123 in excel. perhaps there is some extra escaping in the library, but i can not find CWriteexcelWorkbookBig on google. is there perhaps some additional info in comments in the php file itself

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach( $arrobjPropertyName as $objProperty ) {
    $newNumber='0'.$objProperty->getUnitNumber();
    $objWriteExcelWorksheet->write( $intRowCount, $intColumnCount++,(string)$newNumber, $objWorkbookContent );
}
```

Read Type Juggling http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Most likely issue is not PHP. I trust Pradeep to have echod it or used it elsewhere and it always shows ok. It is the magic excell stuff that is getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate fixed width number strings with [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

`$textnum = sprintf("%04d", $objProperty->getUnitNumber());`

`sprintf` can also help encapsulating the number in quotes, if that is necessary for it to be recognized as a string:

`$textnum = sprintf("'%04d'", $objProperty->getUnitNumber());`